# How could I add a column which contains dates in my SQL query to get the monthly data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with many columns. One contains 50k custIDs, date & Payments received for every id and the other table contains 5k custIDs. I need to find How much payment received per CustId on monthly basis for these 5k CustIDs ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need to edit this question, show all table definitions, sample data, expected results

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are stored as date...

```
select i.custId, i.custName, 
  to_char(p.payment_date,'yyyy-mm') as payment_month, 
  sum(p.amount_paid) as total_amount_paid
from customers i 
join payments p 
  on i.custId = p.custId 
group by i.custId, i.custName, to_char(p.payment_date,'yyyy-mm')
```

Comment: Please consider clicking on the Accept flag if this resolves your question.